# I want to print hard copy forms and staff like

Tags: python, temporary-files, python-os

I want to print hard copy forms, receipts, and stuff like that from my UI. I tried to write to a PDF file. It goes well, but it is not printing at all. I have a definition to do this task. And you can find this `coustom_PDF` from
https://github.com/codewithawr/school_project/blob/main/create_table_fpdf2.py

```
import os
import tempfile
import coustom_PDF

def print_from_printer(form_Heading, Chart_heder, lists):
    temp_file = tempfile.mktemp('.pdf')

    pdf = coustom_PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Times", size=11)

    wirth_cell = [20, 15, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]
    pdf.create_table(table_header=list(Chart_heder), table_data = list(lists), title=form_Heading, title_size=20, cell_width=wirth_cell, data_size=10, align_data='C', x_start='C', emphasize_data=["Abdul Wahab", "p"], emphasize_color = (0, 0, 255))
    pdf.ln()
    pdf.output(temp_file)
    print(temp_file)
    os.startfile(temp_file, 'print')

heding = f'                  School Name or Date\n                      |Fess Chart Of Class 10|'
he = ("First_Name", 'Roll_No', 'Class', 'Jan', 'Fab', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'July', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nav', 'Des')
data = [
    ['Abdul Wahaab', '1234', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['Abdul Hadi', '1234', '10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','0', '0', '0']
]
print_from_printer(form_Heading=heding, Chart_heder=he, lists=data)
```

Comment: There are many misspellings/typos and inconsistencies in that code: "[Fab](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/February#Proper_noun)", "[Agu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/August#Proper_noun)", "July" (four letters), "Chart_heder" ([header](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/header#Noun). Or *[heading](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heading#Noun)*?), and "[`heding`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heading#Noun)". "Nav" ([Nov](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/November#Proper_noun)?) and "Des" ([Dec](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/December#Proper_noun)?) seem to be too far out (from some other language?).

Comment: You can [edit (change) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69657703/edit) - to express the original intent (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today). There isn't any need to comment - just edit, please.